# Chatbase certificate has expired in Sep, 7th

Tags: chatbase

Chatbase API (api.chatbase.com) certificate has expired in Sep, 7th.

[Certificate error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL2JL.png)

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/3001761)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is resolved now. To verify, you can visit https://api.chatbase.com which should display a page with "Not Found" if working correctly or display a certificate error if it is not.